# How to connect SolAdmin to VMR running in AWS?

Tags: message-queue, solace

I have my amazon aws pem key. How do I use authentication mode in Soladmin GUI to connect to VMR running on AWS?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do use the PEM key for SolAdmin because those are actually two completely different types of login.

Refer to the [VMR organization diagram](http://docs.solace.com/Solace-VMR-Set-Up/VMR-Machine-Organization.htm).

The PEM key is what you use to have sysadmin access to the VMR's Linux Host Shell via port 2222. In contrast, the admin credentials you use to connect to the SolAdmin GUI to port 8080 resides in the Application Container (used by SolOS CLI as well).

If you haven't set up your credentials on the Application Container, follow the instructions in the [Configuring Users in the Cloud](http://docs.solace.com/Solace-VMR-Set-Up/Configuring-Users-in-the-Cloud.htm) page to setup the password for a CLI admin user.

Then, you can use the CLI user and password to connect to the VMR with SolAdmin on port 8080. The same credentials will also give you CLI access on port 22 via SSH.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now able to connect to the VMR in AWS using the SolAdmin GUI after setting up a user credential as you outlined!